# How to keep dynamic popup displaying on hover

Tags: angular, popup, angular-dynamic-components

I have created a dynamic popup in angular that appears when I hover over span(or button) but disappear when I leave that span. I cannot figure out how to keep that popup displaying when I'm hovering over it. Gotta be some simple solution I guess( Would appreciate any help.

Here is the link for  app  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khoagq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone is interested. I've managed to solve this. Edited it at the same link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khoagq / What I've done: - moved popup state managing out of directive to component; - added host directive which will contain dynamic component. I'm still not satisfied with this solution. Would like to have something more reusable instead of copying managing methods to each component where I want to have popup.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to hide the popup on mouseleave you need to delete this part of the code in your popup.directive file:

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.hideCallout();
  }



@HostListener('mouseleave')
  hideCallout() {
    if (this.calloutRef && !this.isClicked) {
     this.calloutRef.destroy();
     this.calloutRef = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to hide popup only when the mouse is over that popup or that span. In all other cases I want to destroy that popup otherwise they will just open upon each other(and in real app there are a lot of <span> that evoke that popup).